# プルリクエスト中でforce pushをしては駄目？

Tags: github

[GitHub のヘルプ](https://help.github.com/ja/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/about-pull-requests)に、以下の通り書かれています。

> プルリクエストにコミットをプッシュする場合、フォースプッシュはしないでください。 フォースプッシュをすると、プルリクエストが壊れることがあります。

しかし実際には、いくつかのリポジトリでフォースプッシュがなされているのを見たことがありますし、2018 年から[フォースプッシュを表示する機能が追加された](https://github.blog/changelog/2018-11-15-force-push-timeline-event/)ことも知っています。つまり、何が起こるか分かっていればフォースプッシュを使っても構わないということだと思っています。

では、このヘルプではどういう意味でフォースプッシュを禁止しているのでしょうか？　「プルリクエストが壊れる」とは具体的に何が起こるのでしょう。フォースプッシュ前のコミットが見えなくなることを指しているのでしょうか？

Comment: FYI: 本家SOにも [GitHub advises “Force pushing can corrupt your pull request.” Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50132325/) 質問がありました（未解決）

Answer (score 2):

プルリクエストは頻繁に出しているのですが、実際には試せておらずあくまで憶測での話になります。

単にコミットをまとめるだけ(squash相当)なら `force push` も問題なさそうですが、
プルリクエスト後に分岐の起点を変えてしまうと(rebase)、壊れるのかなと思っています。

**元の状態**

```
A---B---C master
     \
      D---E---F topic (You)
```

**改変後 (コミットを圧縮)**

```
A---B---C master
     \
      D' topic (You)
```

**改変後 (分岐の起点を変更)**

```
A---B---C master
         \
          D'---E'---F' topic (You)
```

Comment: 分岐の起点が変わったらどの情報が失われることを想定されていますか？　3-way merge自体はこれでも行えますよね。

Answer (score 2):

ヘルプを読んでもどういう状態を壊れると書かれているのかが僕も分かりませんでしたが、
レビューでコメント等を入れている場合に紐付け（整合性）が取れなくなることをさしているのかもしれません。
（指摘しているコードの位置と今の位置が合ってないとか）

コミットが表示されなくなるとかマージできなくなるというのは経験ありませんね。

Comment: 自分も[change base](https://help.github.com/ja/github/collaborating-with-issues-and-pull-requests/changing-the-base-branch-of-a-pull-request)のところに書いている警告と同じようなことを言いたいのかな、と思いました。